# How to set variables on CVS

Tags: repository, cvs, csh

I've been tasked with logging into a cvs repository hosted by someone else. I do not know much about cvs. I am supposed to change so option under my .cshrc file, such as:

setenv CVSEDITOR

setenv CVSROOT

setenv CVS_RSH

I am using bash on Mac OSX and I believe I found a file called csh.cshrc, but I cannot edit it and I'm not even sure if that is the correct file I am looking for. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't really specific to CVS. It's about setting environment variables. The file `.cshrc` is for the [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell). Given that you said you are using **bash**, the file you need is `.bashrc` in your home directory.

At it's simplest, you can set the relevant environment variables like so:

```
export CVSEDITOR=...
export CVSROOT=...
export CVS_RSH=...
```

Those are probably the only ones you will need, but you should refer to the [full list](http://cvsman.com/cvs-1.12.12/cvs_207.php) if you want something more.